# Doesn't Samesite cookie and Sameorigin policy effectively does the same job?

Tags: cookies, same-origin-policy

Pardon me if I am wrong, however, I am looking for an answer for my understanding that isn't the concerns regarding CSRF solved by both Samesite cookie and Same-Origin-Policy effectively? Then why is the need for 2 different things?

The basic difference which I can recollect:

`Same-Origin-Policy (SOP)`: Is a policy set by the browser to protect a user from not letting it read the contents of another site unless the origin is same or CORS is implemented effectively

`Samesite Cookie`: On the other hand a job done by a server to mark a cookie to be strict or laxed as per their requirement

Is it just this? is there really a good reason behind having two different ways to prevent CSRF attacks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Same-Origin-Policy does not prevent CSRF attacks. It does not prevent the request from being send and it does not prevent site specific credentials (i.e. session cookie) to be attached to the request. It only prevents cross-origin reading, not cross-origin writing. Thus it is possible to send a fully authenticated request (i.e. with session cookie implicitly attached) cross-site which allows an attacker to do an authorized action on the server side even though the attacker cannot directly get the result of the action (i.e. read the response).

Same-Site cookies mitigate this problem with an additional restriction when a cookie will be implicitly attached to a request. Without same-site property it will be attached to all requests which includes cross-site requests. With same-site property it will no longer be attached to cross-site requests. Thus it is still possible to write cross-site, but not with cookie based authentication information implicitly attached.

Comment: Great, that helps me to clear my thought process. So effectively it is the read action which is blocked by SOP, not the POST or write actions wherein if an attacker gets a hold of a cookie assuming by XXS then they could make a POST request from cross site. Is my understanding correct ? (Thus same site cookie helps)

Comment: @JigerJain: yes, SOP just prevents the read and same-site cookie prevents attaching the cookie to the write.

Comment: @JigerJain "wherein if an attacker gets a hold of a cookie assuming by XXS" The attacker doesn't necessarily need to get hold of a cookie in order to send a POST request containing that cookie. The browser attaches cookies to requests automatically, so the attacker can just send a POST request to the target site and the browser will attach the cookie to that request automatically unless the cookie is marked as SameSite. This is known as a Cross-Site Request Forgery attack, if you want to look up more information on that.

Comment: What does it mean "attaching" cross-site exactly? If SOP prevents reading then how the cookie is obtained in the first place (or are we assuming the cookie is already exploited by "implicitly attaching"?) And also how it's attached? Like automatically by the browser (thru headers) or by crafting the request manually?

Comment: @zgulser: A common CSRF attack is assuming that the user is logged into the target site already, i.e. that there is an existing session cookie. With CSRF the request to the target site is triggered visiting the attacker site, i.e. causing some action on the same target with existing authentication but controlled by the attacker.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see..This sort of attack can also be employed w/out the user having to visit the attacker's website right? Like through an injected malicious link in the victim's html page. In that case, it seems like neither SameSite nor CRSF token would help

Comment: @zgulser: *"... injected malicious link in the victim's html page"* - It is unclear what you mean with "victims html page". If  you mean a malicious link to the target injected at a html page serviced by the target - this would not a a cross-site request at all and thus it would not be a CSRF attack.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's exactly what I mean actually. and it's clear why it's not called CRSF. indeed it's not cross-site. that would rather be HTML injection or sth. I'd considered that as a CSRF attack as it's like tricking users into doing something that they don't intend to do.

Comment: @zgulser: Since it is not a CSRF attack then this question and answer do not apply to it. There are many attacks which "trick users doing something they don't intend to be" - but this is not what cross-site attacks are about. Different kind of attacks usually need different kinds of protection.